# Image display based on criteria - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an invoice using VBA. and I have a cell (D10) that shows either Paid or Not Paid.

If D10 is equal to "Paid" I want it to display an Image, if it is "Not Paid" I want it to show no image'

This is the code I'm trying...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Purpose: Change view between given image and no image
Dim sImgName As String                     ' picture name string
sImgName = "C:\Users\dhamm\Desktop\paid.jpg"        ' <<< choose your picture name"
With Me.sPaidShp
  If .Picture Is Nothing Then             ' picture property has been cleared already
     .Picture = LoadPicture(sImgName)
  Else                                    ' a picture is already displayed
     .Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString) ' clear it now
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Purpose: Change view between given image and no image
Dim sImgName As String                     ' picture name string
If Range("D10").Value = "Paid" Then
    sImgName = "C:\Users\dhamm\Desktop\paid.jpg"        ' <<< choose your picture name"
Else
    sImgName = "C:\Users\dhamm\Desktop\notpaid.jpg"
End If
With Me.sPaidShp
  If .Picture Is Nothing Then             ' picture property has been cleared already
     .Picture = LoadPicture(sImgName)
  Else                                    ' a picture is already displayed
     .Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString) ' clear it now
  End If
End With
End Sub
```